# Валидация произвольного map

Tags: java, валидация

Делаю процессинг обработки документов. Внутри процессинга спрятано несколько процессоров (zip, image processing), которые не имеют общей четкой структуры аргументов. Входящий запрос может выглядеть так:

```
{
    "sourceDocumentId": "b4e8d214-9473-4d41-83c9-06e5491c18d3",
    "pipeline": [
        {
            "processor": "image",
            "arguments": {
                "pipeline": [
                    {
                        "processor": "resize",
                        "arguments": {
                            "width": 200,
                            "height": 150
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "processor": "crop",
                        "arguments": {
                            "width": 100,
                            "height": 100,
                            "snap": "center"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "processor": "zip",
            "arguments": {
                "compression": "HIGH"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Все это дело требуется валидировать (существование процессора с указанным именем, поддержку mime-type на протяжении всего пайплайна - что следующий процессор принимает выходной mime-type, корректность аргументов), чтобы отказывать клиенту до начала процессинга в случае предоставления неверных опций, причем предполагается, что добавление нового процессора представляет собой просто добавление новой имплементации интерфейса в контейнер. Как можно организовать подобную валидацию на основе валидатора hibernate?

Answer (score 1):

В результате задача была решена окольным (но, на мой взгляд, правильным) путем.

Вышеприведенный payload парсится с помощью jackson, и я написал простой функционал для конвертации вышеописанной структуры в конкретные классы. В контейнере приложения существуют реализации интерфейсов `DocumentProcessor` и `ImageProcessor` (первые принимают `InputStream` и `OutputStream`, вторые - `BufferedImage`), которые явно указывают свое название и тип объекта принимаемых аргументов. При парсинге кастомный десериализатор сначала просматривает доступные в контейнере просматривает выгрузку этих реализаций, из выгрузки берет конкретный процессор, из процессора подтягивает нужный класс аргументов, ищет кастомный десериализатор этого класса, если находит, десериализует с его помощью, а если не находит - использует `ObjectMapper` для конвертации аргументов в нужный тип. Таким образом при десериализации вышеуказанного payload находится процессор с названием `"image"`, получается тип его аргументов, находится нужный десериализатор, вызывается, десериализатор получает на вход исходную Map, десериализует ее в промежуточный объект `List<{processor:string, arguments:map}>`, для каждого `processor` ищет класс контейнера аргументов (если не находит, использует контейнер по умолчанию на основе map), для каждого контейнера ищет десериализатор, после чего, наконец, запускает десериализатор или использует `ObjectMapper` для десериализации.
Выходная система очень тупая и негибкая, но в результате на выходе получается строгая структура, отвалидировать которую легко с помощью простых аннотаций. Jackson сам по себе предлагает [полиморфную десериализацию](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonPolymorphicDeserialization), которая значительно упрощает работу, но в данном проекте от нее решено было отказаться из-за некоторых причин.

Сам вопрос касательно валидации map остается открытым.